# get and update cells in individual google sheet (specific sheet in spreadsheet)

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Google spreadsheets are made up of one or more individual sheets (shown as tabs on the bottom of the web ui). The [v4 sheets api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values) makes it fairly clear how to to manipulate cells in the default sheet in a spreadsheet, but I can't seem to figure out how to specify a different sheet for read/write operations.

Any information on how to do this with the java or rest api would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of use for reading (`values.get`) and writing (`values.update`) data to cells for the existing Spreadsheet, you can use the specific sheet in the Spreadsheet using A1 notation for Range. The detail information of A1 notation is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation).

#### Read operation : `values.get`

About `values.get` of Sheets API v4 which is used for retrieving cell values in the sheet, You can see the sample script at [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get).

In the sample script, you can retrieve the cell values by modifying`String spreadsheetId = "my-spreadsheet-id";` and `String range = "my-range";`. For example, `Sheet2!A1:B2` for the range retrieves the first two cells in the top two rows of Sheet2.

#### Write operation : `values.update`

About `values.update` of Sheets API v4 which is used for updating cell values in the sheet, You can see the sample script at [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update).

In the sample script, you can update the cell values by modifying like the same to above.

#### Note :

If you use sample script, at first, please check [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java). After that, please check `TODO` in the sample script.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: That's clear enough to get things working. It is annoying though that there is no way to change the default sheet and use relative A1 notation rather than always prefixing with the sheet name.